# Single text column to a row

Tags: python, python-2.7

Simple question but I can't find the answer. I have a csv file with a list of names in a column. The number of names will vary by file. I want to change it to  a row of names and output to a simple text file.

homer simpson
bart simpson
marg simpson
lisa simpson

output to homer simpson bart simpson marg simpson lisa simpson

Appreciate any help.
Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to read the csv, then transpose it and output the values into a .txt file using [numpy.savetxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Read the input .csv file
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',header=None)

#Transpose the columns to rows
df_row = df.transpose()

#Output the dataframe to .txt file
np.savetxt('out.txt',df_row.values,delimiter=' ',fmt='%s')
```

I have not set the delimiter since the example in your question did not specify any. You can change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in pandas - solution with csv:

```
import csv
fp1=open('simpson.csv')
root = csv.reader(fp1)

for line in root:
    #Eliminates [] from list output
    print ''.join(line),
```

(obviously I supposed file was named simpson.csv)